# Cannot get Font Awesome to work with jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, font-awesome

I am trying to get Font Awesome working on a jQuery tab page, and I am trying to use "nest" mode, as described here:

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/jquery

Here is my "nesting" call to the font-awesome file:

```
<script defer src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>
```

Please take a look at my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/r0Lbojz2/

Everything looks good on the initial load, the problem occurs when after you click the Play button and wait until the bar reaches the end. There is supposed to be a Refresh button from FontAwesome that appears, which if you click again will restart the progress bar. Why is the Refresh button not appearing, but the Play and Pause buttons are?

```js
// jQuery Tabs JavaScript
$("#tabs").tabs();

// Highcharts JavaScript

// Bar chart Javascript:

const startYear = 1960,
  // endYear = 2018,
  endYear = 1965,
  btn = document.getElementById('play-pause-button'),
  input = document.getElementById('play-range'),
  nbr = 20;

let dataset, chart;


/*
 * Animate dataLabels functionality
 */
(function(H) {
  const FLOAT = /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/;

  // Add animated textSetter, just like fill/strokeSetters
  H.Fx.prototype.textSetter = function() {
    let startValue = this.start.replace(/ /g, ''),
      endValue = this.end.replace(/ /g, ''),
      currentValue = this.end.replace(/ /g, '');

    if ((startValue || '').match(FLOAT)) {
      startValue = parseInt(startValue, 10);
      endValue = parseInt(endValue, 10);

      // No support for float
      currentValue = Highcharts.numberFormat(
        Math.round(startValue + (endValue - startValue) * this.pos),
        0
      );
    }

    this.elem.endText = this.end;

    this.elem.attr(this.prop, currentValue, null, true);
  };

  // Add textGetter, not supported at all at this moment:
  H.SVGElement.prototype.textGetter = function() {
    const ct = this.text.element.textContent || '';
    return this.endText ? this.endText : ct.substring(0, ct.length / 2);
  };

  // Temporary change label.attr() with label.animate():
  // In core it's simple change attr(...) => animate(...) for text prop
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function(proceed) {
    const attr = H.SVGElement.prototype.attr,
      chart = this.chart;

    if (chart.sequenceTimer) {
      this.points.forEach(point =>
        (point.dataLabels || []).forEach(
          label =>
          (label.attr = function(hash) {
            if (hash && hash.text !== undefined) {
              const text = hash.text;

              delete hash.text;

              return this
                .attr(hash)
                .animate({
                  text
                });
            }
            return attr.apply(this, arguments);

          })
        )
      );
    }

    const ret = proceed.apply(
      this,
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
    );

    this.points.forEach(p =>
      (p.dataLabels || []).forEach(d => (d.attr = attr))
    );

    return ret;
  });
}(Highcharts));


function getData(year) {
  const output = Object.entries(dataset)
    .map(country => {
      const [countryName, countryData] = country;

      return [countryName, Number(countryData[year])];
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  return [output[0], output.slice(1, nbr)];
}

function getSubtitle() {
  const population = (getData(input.value)[0][1] / 1000000000).toFixed(2);
  return `<span style="font-size: 80px">${input.value}</span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 22px">
            Total: <b>: ${population}</b> billion
        </span>`;
}

(async() => {

  dataset = await fetch(
    'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/population.json'
  ).then(response => response.json());


  chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      animation: {
        duration: 500
      },
      marginRight: 50
    },
    title: {
      text: 'World population by country',
      align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
      useHTML: true,
      text: getSubtitle(),
      floating: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: -20,
      x: -100
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
      opposite: true,
      tickPixelInterval: 150,
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: false,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0.1,
        borderWidth: 0,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataSorting: {
          enabled: true,
          matchByName: true
        },
        type: 'bar',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'bar',
      name: startYear,
      data: getData(startYear)[1]
    }],
    responsive: {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 550
        },
        chartOptions: {
          xAxis: {
            visible: false
          },
          subtitle: {
            x: 0
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              dataLabels: [{
                enabled: true,
                y: 8
              }, {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}',
                y: -8,
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  opacity: 0.7
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  });


})();



/*
 * Pause the timeline, either when the range is ended, or when clicking the pause button.
 * Pausing stops the timer and resets the button to play mode.
 */
function pause(button, shouldBeRefresh) {
  if (shouldBeRefresh) {
    button.title = 'refresh';
    button.className = 'fa  fa-refresh';
  } else {
    button.title = 'play';
    button.className = 'fa fa-play';
  }

  clearTimeout(chart.sequenceTimer);
  chart.sequenceTimer = undefined;
}

/*
 * Update the chart. This happens either on updating (moving) the range input,
 * or from a timer when the timeline is playing.
 */
function update(increment) {
  if (increment) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value, 10) + increment;
  }
  if (input.value >= endYear) {
    // Auto-pause
    pause(btn, true);
  }

  chart.update({
      subtitle: {
        text: getSubtitle()
      }
    },
    false,
    false,
    false
  );


  chart.series[0].update({
    name: input.value,
    data: getData(input.value)[1]
  });
}

/*
 * Play the timeline.
 */
function play(button) {
  button.title = 'pause';
  button.className = 'fa fa-pause';
  chart.sequenceTimer = setInterval(function() {
    update(1);
  }, 500);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.title === 'refresh') {
    input.value = 1960 - 1
    play(this);
  } else {
    if (chart.sequenceTimer) {
      pause(this);
    } else {
      play(this);
    }
  }
});
/*
 * Trigger the update on the range bar click.
 */
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (btn.title === 'refresh') {
    play(btn)
  }
  update();
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script defer src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>

<div id="div-container">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Dude, Where's My Refresh Button?</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="parent-container">
          <div id="play-controls">
            <button id="play-pause-button" class="fa fa-play" title="play"></button>
            <input id="play-range" type="range" value="1960" min="1960" max="1965" />
          </div>
          <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example IN your question that reproduces your issue (suggest a snippet here). Asking someone to wade through all that fiddle is a bit much.
FWIW your fiddle CSS is invalid right there at the top

Comment: See my revised fiddle. I removed all of the CSS and changed the ending year from 2018 to 1965 to make the error appear faster. I tried to remove the Highcharts chart altogether but I wasn't able to reproduce the error then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no "refresh" icon.  Suggest using an alternate one like
`button.className = 'fa  fa-redo';`

```js
console.clear();
$("#tabs").tabs();
const startYear = 1960,
  endYear = 1965,
  btn = document.getElementById('play-pause-button'),
  input = document.getElementById('play-range'),
  nbr = 20;

let dataset, chart;

/*
 * Animate dataLabels functionality
 */
(function(H) {
  const FLOAT = /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/;
  // Add animated textSetter, just like fill/strokeSetters
  H.Fx.prototype.textSetter = function() {
    let startValue = this.start.replace(/ /g, ''),
      endValue = this.end.replace(/ /g, ''),
      currentValue = this.end.replace(/ /g, '');
    if ((startValue || '').match(FLOAT)) {
      startValue = parseInt(startValue, 10);
      endValue = parseInt(endValue, 10);
      // No support for float
      currentValue = Highcharts.numberFormat(
        Math.round(startValue + (endValue - startValue) * this.pos),
        0
      );
    }
    this.elem.endText = this.end;
    this.elem.attr(this.prop, currentValue, null, true);
  };
  // Add textGetter, not supported at all at this moment:
  H.SVGElement.prototype.textGetter = function() {
    const ct = this.text.element.textContent || '';
    return this.endText ? this.endText : ct.substring(0, ct.length / 2);
  };
  // Temporary change label.attr() with label.animate():
  // In core it's simple change attr(...) => animate(...) for text prop
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function(proceed) {
    const attr = H.SVGElement.prototype.attr,
      chart = this.chart;
    if (chart.sequenceTimer) {
      this.points.forEach(point =>
        (point.dataLabels || []).forEach(
          label =>
          (label.attr = function(hash) {
            if (hash && hash.text !== undefined) {
              const text = hash.text;
              delete hash.text;
              return this
                .attr(hash)
                .animate({
                  text
                });
            }
            return attr.apply(this, arguments);
          })
        )
      );
    }
    const ret = proceed.apply(
      this,
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
    );
    this.points.forEach(p =>
      (p.dataLabels || []).forEach(d => (d.attr = attr))
    );
    return ret;
  });
}(Highcharts));

function getData(year) {
  const output = Object.entries(dataset)
    .map(country => {
      const [countryName, countryData] = country;
      return [countryName, Number(countryData[year])];
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  return [output[0], output.slice(1, nbr)];
}

function getSubtitle() {
  const population = (getData(input.value)[0][1] / 1000000000).toFixed(2);
  return `<span style="font-size: 80px">${input.value}</span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 22px">
            Total: <b>: ${population}</b> billion
        </span>`;
}

(async() => {
  dataset = await fetch(
    'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/population.json'
  ).then(response => response.json());
  chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      animation: {
        duration: 500
      },
      marginRight: 50
    },
    title: {
      text: 'World population by country',
      align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
      useHTML: true,
      text: getSubtitle(),
      floating: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: -20,
      x: -100
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
      opposite: true,
      tickPixelInterval: 150,
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: false,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0.1,
        borderWidth: 0,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataSorting: {
          enabled: true,
          matchByName: true
        },
        type: 'bar',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'bar',
      name: startYear,
      data: getData(startYear)[1]
    }],
    responsive: {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 550
        },
        chartOptions: {
          xAxis: {
            visible: false
          },
          subtitle: {
            x: 0
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              dataLabels: [{
                enabled: true,
                y: 8
              }, {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}',
                y: -8,
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  opacity: 0.7
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  });
})();



/*
 * Pause the timeline, either when the range is ended, or when clicking the pause button.
 * Pausing stops the timer and resets the button to play mode.
 */
function pause(button, shouldBeRefresh) {
  if (shouldBeRefresh) {
    button.title = 'refresh';
    button.className = 'fa  fa-redo';
  } else {
    button.title = 'play';
    button.className = 'fa fa-play';
  }
  clearTimeout(chart.sequenceTimer);
  chart.sequenceTimer = undefined;
}

/*
 * Update the chart. This happens either on updating (moving) the range input,
 * or from a timer when the timeline is playing.
 */
function update(increment) {
  if (increment) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value, 10) + increment;
  }
  if (input.value >= endYear) {
    // Auto-pause
    pause(btn, true);
  }
  chart.update({
      subtitle: {
        text: getSubtitle()
      }
    },
    false,
    false,
    false
  );
  chart.series[0].update({
    name: input.value,
    data: getData(input.value)[1]
  });
}

/*
 * Play the timeline.
 */
function play(button) {
  button.title = 'pause';
  button.className = 'fa fa-pause';
  chart.sequenceTimer = setInterval(function() {
    update(1);
  }, 500);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  //console.log(this,this.title === 'refresh');
  if (this.title === 'refresh') {
    input.value = startYear - 1;
    play(this);
  } else {
    //console.log("timer", chart.sequenceTimer);
    if (chart.sequenceTimer) {
      pause(this);
    } else {
      play(this);
    }
  }
});
/*
 * Trigger the update on the range bar click.
 */
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (btn.title === 'refresh') {
    play(btn);
  }
  update();
});
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script defer src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>

<div id="div-container">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Dude, Where's My Refresh Button?</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="parent-container">
          <div id="play-controls">
            <button id="play-pause-button" class="fa fa-play" title="play"></button>
            <input id="play-range" type="range" value="1960" min="1960" max="1965" />
          </div>
          <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing the class name from "fa-refresh" to "fa-redo" fixed the issue.